# execute media files from AIR 3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, air, media

I know that since AIR 2.0 it is possible to execute applications (.exe) like this:

```
if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
{
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
    file = file.resolvePath("StyleLookupold.exe");

    var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
    var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();

    process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

}
```

But is it possible to open a video in system's default player?  For example executing Windows Media Player with command line parameter being the path to the video to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Open_file_with_Default_Application_AIR_2_0-16745.html Use openWithDefaultApplication method on the File object available in AIR 2 and greater.

Comment: No problem just happened to recall seeing that method, haven't used it yet but best of luck.